# accessing Ondemand Bamboo instance's maven repository

Tags: maven, cloudbees, bamboo

I am having some doubts/queries  about setting up  Ondemand Bamboo instance. I am having cloud based Git repository. I want to checkout source code, build my project with Maven 3.x and access generated  maven artifacts repository.

Q:do Ondemand Bamboo instance provide  maven repository access ?

[Cloubees](http://cloudbees.com/) is providing this facility: it provides a maven central proxy that's nexus based and a private repository. So, in case of Cloudbees, developer has to point to repository hosted at CloudBees location https://repository-myproject.forge.cloudbees.com/release

Q: Is the similar facility available with Ondemand Bamboo setup? 
If yes, to access maven repository, do I need to keep my Bamboo's Image-instance always in 'START' mode?
IF No,  how can I transfer artifacts to  locally hosted Nexus server?   Is it possible to FTP/ upload from Bamboo instance to  different server?

Any help/hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On cloudbees, the default maven configuration is set so that those maven repositories are available by default, so you don't have anything to configure. I don't think bamboo embrace the maven build process such a way

Comment: yes, you are right. Bamboo is not supporting maven repository like Cloudbees.